# How to hide/remove "exit, minimize, maximize" bar on top of the application when not maximized, showing only the application/program on the desktop

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz

I'm an on and off novice ubuntu user, last used 9.04 and installed 11.10 a week ago. What I want to happen, edit unity to suit how I use my computer:

- Copy the way **xmonad** *(www.xmonad.org)* shows its applications and that is that there is no "exit, minimize, maximize" bar on top of the application

I've read a few things on how to configure unity using [Ubuntu Tweak](http://www.ubuntu-tweak.com) and [MyUnity](http://www.launchpad.net/myunity)

I want to eventually switch to xmonad but for now it is still too complicated for me even with all the docs & tutorialss it's still too complicated for me & I cannot yet let go of my mouse

### tl;dr?

from this:

[image]

to this

[image]

Is this possible? And if it is possible, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to remove the complete window border:

Install [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager)[image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open it via `ccsm` or out of the dash.

Disable the plugin "Window Decoration" (under "Effects") by unchecking it:

[image: ccsm]